# Handling Ajax Request in JSP Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am working with an example with JSP and Ajax to throw a name and a sum, but i do not see the window with the result. These are my files

I could not find the error, or where they think or as your thin i can fix it?

**index.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<title>Demo Ajax</title>

<link href="/resources/css/miPrimerCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#unHola').click(function(){
         var nombreCompleto = $('#nombreCompleto').val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             data: {
                 nombreCompleto : nombreCompleto,
                 action: 'demo1'
             },
             url: 'AjaxController',
             success: function(result){
                 $('#resultado1').html(result);
             }

         });
     });

     $('#unaSuma').click(function(){
         var numero1 = $('#numero1').val();
         var numero2 = $('#numero2').val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             data: {
                 numero1 : numero1,
                 numero2 : numero2,  
                 action: 'demo2'
             },
             url:'AjaxController',
             success : function(result){
                 $('#resultado2').html(result);
             }

         });
     }); 



  }); // $(document).ready(function()

</script>
</head>
<!-- <span id="titulo">Un Saludo</span>
<p style="font-size: 20px">Un Hola<p>

-->
 <body>

     <fieldset>
        <h1>Un Hola</h1>
           <form>
              Nombre <input type="text" id="nombreCompleto"><br>
              <input type="button" value="Hola" id="unHola"><br> 
              <span id="resultado1"></span>
           </form>
     </fieldset>


     <fieldset>
          <h2>Una Suma</h2>
             <form>
                Numero 1 <input type="text" id="numero1"><br>
                Numero 2 <input type="text" id="numero2"><br> 
                Resultado <span id=resultado2></span><br>
                <input type="button" value="Suma" id="unaSuma">


             </form>
    </fieldset>



  </body>

</html>
```

**AjaxController.java**

```
package controladores;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxController
 */
@WebServlet("/AjaxController")
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain ");

        PrintWriter out =  response.getWriter();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if(action.equals("demo1")){
            String nombreCompleto = request.getParameter("nombreCompleto");
            out.println("Hola " + nombreCompleto);
        }
        else if (action.equals("demo2")){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero1"));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero2"));
            out.println(a + b);
        }



    }

}
```

the example should have been so

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rerun your code in my context and it runs as expected after the following fixes. Try them :

- Your **JQuery** may not loaded properly. Try to make sure this import URL is valid and runs  `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>`
- Think about using some **jstl taglib** support for loading context relative resources like this `<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>`
- Place your `<script></script>` s to the end of body. Actually it is a good practice to load JS files at the end of body, thus it doesn't block the page loading.

**Some more tips :**

- You need not to declare constructor in you Servlet unless you really plan about any custom things
- If you dont use `doGet()` then dont keep it in Servlet.

Comment: i found the solution by adding the library directly on a URL and not from the "Web-Content" : "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"

Comment: yes, thats another way to attach static resources. It also works and hustle free.